# Jquery - How to make below code dynamic & clean using array loop iteration

Tags: jquery

Created below HTML/JS for form submission if values are entered. This works fine as expected.

But, Code looks very long for simple form submission. Like this we need to do for 6 more locations. Code go beyond 300 lines for this function. As, ID of each containers are different. Just have to duplicate and change ID names of each element.

Please guide or comments to help me to make this function more clean than this existing one.

Thanks

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container location-container multi-cityTrip--Container">
    <div class="row" id="multicity-selection--1">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 multicity-fromlocation--one form-validate">
        <div class="multicity-form--title">From</div>
        <select class="select form-control input-lg multi-location" id="multiCityFromLocationOne" name="multiCityfromLocation1" data-multidepartloc1="Departure airport Location1 is missing" data-multideptDestLoc1="Departure1 and Destination1 Locations are same"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 one-direction"><i class="fa fa-plane from-direction" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 multicity-tolocation--one form-validate">
        <div class="multicity-form--title">To</div>
        <select class="select form-control input-lg multi-location" id="multiCityToLocationOne" name="multiCitytoLocation1" data-multidestloc1="Destination airport Location1 is missing" data-multideptDestLoc1="Departure1 and Destination1 Locations are same"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <div class="book-date--selector">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-validate">
            <div class="booking-form--title one">
              <div class="multi-dep-title">Departure</div>
            </div><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <input class="form-control input-lg" id="multiCityTripInputOne" name="MulticityTripOne" data-multitraveldate1="Departure date 1 is missing" readonly="true">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 remove-flight"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="multicity-selection--2">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 multicity-fromlocation--two form-validate">
        <div class="multicity-form--title">From</div>
        <select class="select form-control input-lg multi-location" id="multiCityFromLocationTwo" name="multiCityfromLocation2" data-multidepartloc2="Departure airport Location2 is missing" data-multideptDestLoc2="Departure2 and Destination2 Locations are same"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 one-direction"><i class="fa fa-plane from-direction" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 multicity-tolocation--two form-validate">
        <div class="multicity-form--title">To</div>
        <select class="select form-control input-lg multi-location" id="multiCityToLocationTwo" name="multiCitytoLocation2" data-multidestloc2="Destination airport Location2 is missing" data-multideptDestLoc2="Departure2 and Destination2 Locations are same"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <div class="book-date--selector">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-validate">
            <div class="booking-form--title two">
              <div class="multi-dep-title">Departure</div>
            </div><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <input class="form-control input-lg" id="multiCityTripInputTwo" name="MulticityTripTwo" data-multitraveldate2="Departure date 2 is missing" readonly="true">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 remove-flight"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="multiSearchForm" type="submit">Find flights</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#multiSearchForm').click(function (et) {
    var $error = [];
    et.preventDefault();
    $('.error-validation').show();
    /* Multi city location 1 */
    if ($('#multiCityFromLocationOne').val() == '') {
        $('select#multiCityFromLocationOne').parent().find('.selectize-control .selectize-input').addClass('has-error');
        $('select#multiCityFromLocationOne').parent().find('.multicity-form--title').addClass('has-error');
        var $multiCityFromLocationOne = $('#multiCityFromLocationOne').attr('data-multidepartloc1');
        $error.push($multiCityFromLocationOne);
    }
    else {
        $('select#multiCityFromLocationOne').parent().find('.selectize-control .selectize-input').removeClass('has-error');
        $('select#multiCityFromLocationOne').parent().find('.multicity-form--title').removeClass('has-error');
    }
    if ($('#multiCityToLocationOne').val() == '') {
        $('select#multiCityToLocationOne').parent().find('.selectize-control .selectize-input').addClass('has-error');
        $('select#multiCityToLocationOne').parent().find('.multicity-form--title').addClass('has-error');
        var $multiCityToLocationOne = $('#multiCityToLocationOne').attr('data-multidestloc1');
        $error.push($multiCityToLocationOne);
    }
    else {
        $('select#multiCityToLocationOne').parent().find('.selectize-control .selectize-input').removeClass('has-error');
        $('select#multiCityToLocationOne').parent().find('.multicity-form--title').removeClass('has-error');
    }
    if ($('#multiCityFromLocationOne').val() === $('#multiCityToLocationOne').val()) {
        $('select#multiCityToLocationOne').parent().find('.selectize-control .selectize-input').addClass('has-error');
        $('select#multiCityToLocationOne').parent().find('.multicity-form--title').addClass('has-error');
        var $multiCityFromToLocationOne = $('#multiCityToLocationOne').attr('data-multideptDestLoc1');
        $error.push($multiCityFromToLocationOne);
    }
    if ($('#multiCityTripInputOne').val() == '') {
        $('#multiCityTripInputOne').parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
        var $multiTravelDate1 = $('#multiCityTripInputOne').attr('data-multitraveldate1');
        $error.push($multiTravelDate1);
    }
    else {
        $('#multiCityTripInputOne').parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
    }
    /* Multi city location 2 */
    if ($('#multiCityFromLocationTwo').val() == '') {
        $('select#multiCityFromLocationTwo').parent().find('.selectize-control .selectize-input').addClass('has-error');
        $('select#multiCityFromLocationTwo').parent().find('.multicity-form--title').addClass('has-error');
        var $multiCityFromLocationTwo = $('#multiCityFromLocationTwo').attr('data-multidepartloc2');
        $error.push($multiCityFromLocationTwo);
    }
    else {
        $('select#multiCityFromLocationTwo').parent().find('.selectize-control .selectize-input').removeClass('has-error');
        $('select#multiCityFromLocationTwo').parent().find('.multicity-form--title').removeClass('has-error');
    }
    if ($('#multiCityToLocationTwo').val() == '') {
        $('select#multiCityToLocationTwo').parent().find('.selectize-control .selectize-input').addClass('has-error');
        $('select#multiCityToLocationTwo').parent().find('.multicity-form--title').addClass('has-error');
        var $multiCityToLocationTwo = $('#multiCityToLocationTwo').attr('data-multidestloc2');
        $error.push($multiCityToLocationTwo);
    }
    else {
        $('select#multiCityToLocationTwo').parent().find('.selectize-control .selectize-input').removeClass('has-error');
        $('select#multiCityToLocationTwo').parent().find('.multicity-form--title').removeClass('has-error');
    }
    if ($('#multiCityFromLocationTwo').val() === $('#multiCityToLocationTwo').val()) {
        $('select#multiCityToLocationTwo').parent().find('.selectize-control .selectize-input').addClass('has-error');
        $('select#multiCityToLocationTwo').parent().find('.multicity-form--title').addClass('has-error');
        var $multiCityFromToLocationTwo = $('#multiCityToLocationTwo').attr('data-multideptDestLoc2');
        $error.push($multiCityFromToLocationTwo);
    }
    if ($('#multiCityTripInputTwo').val() == '') {
        $('#multiCityTripInputTwo').parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
        var $multiTravelDate2 = $('#multiCityTripInputTwo').attr('data-multitraveldate2');
        $error.push($multiTravelDate2);
    }
    else {
        $('#multiCityTripInputTwo').parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, consolidate what you call your errors.  Have one error attribute.  Like "error".  That will cut back on a lot of lines.  Next, Here's a potential rewrite.  It loops through all selects and all inputs and will add an error, if need be.  You should think of a better name for hasError1 and hasError2. (Since I don't know the context of your code, I couldn't do it myself.)

```
<script>
$('#multiSearchForm').click(function (et) {
    var $error = [];
    et.preventDefault();
    $('.error-validation').show();
    $(".container input, .container selector").each(function () {
        hasError1 = (this).parent().find('.selectize-control .selectize-input');
        hasError2 = (this).parent().find('.multicity-form--title');
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            hasError1.addClass('has-error');
            hasError2.addClass('has-error');
            $error.push($(this).attr('error'));
        } else {
            hasError1.removeClass('has-error');
            hasError2.removeClass('has-error');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

(A side note: if you're also trying to consolidate the HTML, if you could post some CSS context, I'll look at that too).

Comment: Hi Neil.. thanks for your reply. Not sure whether i need to change some of my HTML codes to make this clean code. Updated all my code in jsfiddle.net.Please verify and let me know. Thanks

Comment: What I was asking was if you could consolidate data-multidepartloc1 and data-multidestloc1 and etc. all into one HTML attribute.  Like an error attribute.  That would make it possible to use the very simple check I wrote above.

Comment: Yes.. its possible.. but, can define different value for depart & arrival location. Also, depart & arrival location should not be same.. if its same, then we need to show other validation message of 'data-multideptDestLoc1'

Comment: Its getting more complex for me to make this logic clean as professional way.